# does snagit opens ai files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

the snagit software only opened eps file extension, but didn't open the ai file? so what is the problem ? does it only open the eps files ? I tried opening the eps and ai but it only opens the eps.

Answer (score 1):

AI files are not EPS files, as of version 9 forward. Older AI files are EPS files of sort, so a version 7 or a version 3 file is an EPS. The newer files however are very complex EPS files and quite many software just can not open them as rasterizing requires a full postscript interpreter. But yes a AI version 3 is EPS.

Newer AI files may sometimes be PDF files though, depending on the settings used.

So to summarize: An AI file may be an EPS, it may be a PDF, or it can be neither.

Comment: Thanks @joojaa and Lucian , But i really don't get it. can you be more clear ?

Comment: @New_spirit_designs No its not possible to be more clear. AI is many different file formats.